# IS it possible to inner join 3 tables for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch certain data by using a column that exists in all 3 tables, I have three tables

- `[Txn].[TxnPaymentResponse]`
- `[Txn].[Txn]`
- `[Txn].[TxnLineItem]`

Right now if I run the query, I'm able to get the correct data only `userID`.

But I want to grab another piece of information (suppose that call column X) from the 3rd table (`TxnLineItem`). That column doesn't exist in the first 2 tables. In this scenario how could I perform inner join and show that piece of info in the query?

```
DECLARE  @CompletedTransactionSince  DATETIME2(7) = '2022-09-13 00:00:00.000000'

SELECT DISTINCT
    t.UserID
FROM    
    [Txn].[Txn] T WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN    
    [Txn].[TxnPaymentResponse] TPR WITH(NOLOCK) ON T.[TxnID] = TPR.[TxnID]
WHERE
    TPR.[PaymentResponseType] = 'FINAL'
    AND TPR.[AuthorizedAmount] > CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,3), 0)
    AND (@CompletedTransactionSince IS NULL OR
         T.[CreatedOn] > @CompletedTransactionSince)
```

Results from my query:

| UserID |
| --- |
| C1671FDA-70A8-4C07-BBDF-ACD06ADD145F |

Table 3:

| TxnID | StandardProductCategory |
| --- | --- |
| 6FE0D0D0-9959-41AA-9BF0-00000003DED8 | Carwash |
| D1B0EA51-C476-488C-A140-0000C1C7D099 | General |

Suppose I'm doing inner join like

```
INNER JOIN    
    [Txn].[TxnLineItem] TXL WITH(NOLOCK) ON T.[TxnID] = [Txn].[TxnID],
```

But my I want to grab the X column that has the same `transactionID`. I want to display `UserID` that has a `Carwash` only. Not sure if it's possible to write another clause with an inner join.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data for the tables involved and the result you want to achieve, based on that sample data

Comment: I want to get the user  who got the car wash

Comment: Can we have proper sample data for all three tables, as well as expected results? At the moment you just have the results of your first query, and the sample for Table3.

Comment: It sounds like you want maybe an `EXISTS` but it's really unclear. Side note: why are you using `NOLOCK`? It's a really bad idea, and there are much better methods if you don't want to block others

Comment: Can we stop calling it column x and actually name the column you want to see? Do you want to see `StandardProductCategory`?

Answer (score 0):

As per "I want to display UserID that has a Carwash only", you need to exclude records.

Just add these EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clauses at the end of to query.

EXISTS part is filter users that has CarWash.

NOT EXISTS part is exclude users that has StandardProduct Category  records other than Car Wash

```
......
AND (@CompletedTransactionSince IS NULL OR
     T.[CreatedOn] > @CompletedTransactionSince)
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM [Txn].[TxnLineItem] TXL 
             WHERE T.[TxnID] = [Txn].[TxnID] 
               AND TXL.StandardProductCategory='Carwash')
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM [Txn].[TxnLineItem] TXL 
                 WHERE T.[TxnID] = [Txn].[TxnID] 
                  AND TXL.StandardProductCategory=<>'Carwash')
```